# qq-plot and hypergeometric distribution (car package)

Tags: r

I'm using the 'car' package to create a qq-plot. I generated some random numbers that follow the hypergeometric distribution, and I wanted to create the qq-plot to verify that they indeed follow the hypergeometric distribution. Unfortunately, I'm encountering the following error message:

```
Error in q.function(P, ...) : argument "m" is missing, with no default
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code provided below:

```
install.packages("car")
library(car)
rh <- rhyper(1000, 12, 40, 5)
qqPlot(rh, dist = "hyper", m = 12, n = 40, k = 5)
```